# PHP paragonie/halite - missing Sodium\ constants?

Tags: php, encryption, php-7.1, libsodium

I want to implement simple encryption.

I'm using newest PHP 7.1.8, and since mcrypt is deprecated, I learned about the libsodium. Installed it, and this is how my PHP info looks:

[image: PHP sodium]

Everything seems to be in order.

And then I installed paragonie/halite v3.2.0, and just tried simple example from the github page:

```
    $passwd = new HiddenString('correct horse battery staple');
    // Use random_bytes(16); to generate the salt:
    $salt = "\xdd\x7b\x1e\x38\x75\x9f\x72\x86\x0a\xe9\xc8\x58\xf6\x16\x0d\x3b";

    $encryptionKey = KeyFactory::deriveEncryptionKey($passwd, $salt);
```

Running this returns:

`Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant 'Sodium\CRYPTO_PWHASH_OPSLIMIT_INTERACTIVE' in /app/vendor/paragonie/halite/src/KeyFactory.php on line 274`

[image]

After looking a bit into the code, I can see that the code really uses these constants.

I've seen that older versions of the PHP extension were used within `\Sodium` namespace, and that since it is confirmed to become PHP7.2 core extension, functions were refactored, to be used as `sodium_*`.

Maybe I'm missing something but my question is, can anyone tell me what could be the reason I'm missing these constants ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, that's strange. I checked the source and the constant is actually defined in [Sodium.stub.php](https://github.com/paragonie/halite/blob/49a324b4c83e52cd8dcf887a9bd71dc832488d22/stub/Sodium.stub.php#L33) In any case, I think you should install a more recent version of libsodium as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37682227/including-paragonie-halite-in-project-doesnt-find-variables-and-functions) @Scott Arciszewski is the maintainer of the project, if the answer doesn't solve your issue, you can ping him

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer @samayo, I will check again the versions and let you know if helped :)

Comment: Although I must admit that it's weird that my extension has the `sodium_*` functions available, but not these constants. I installed the extension with standard `pecl install libsodium`. Gonna try to select a specific version.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with a simple version specification:

`pecl install libsodium-1.0.6`

Not sure what's going on under the hood, but my guess is that my version of `paragonie/halite` wasn't completely adapted to the newest `sodium` PHP extension. Maybe this will be resolved for the upcoming PHP7.2, when it becomes a core PHP extension.

For now I'm sticking with this version.